# The radius is bigger than 8587.0 and hence we'll use that value

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I have an uber app where i need to query the customer location , i set my initial radius to 1 , and the application was working fine , after sometime without any changes made of my part , it started throwing this error which i will show below , any help is appreciated Thank you

Error :

> The radius is bigger than 8587.0 and hence we'll use that value

Code:

```
private fun getNearByDrivers(){
    val geoFire = GeoFire(driverAvailableRef)
    val geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(GeoLocation(customPickUpLocation.latitude,customPickUpLocation.longitude),radius)
    geoQuery.removeAllListeners()
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(object  : GeoQueryEventListener{
        override fun onKeyEntered(key: String?, location: GeoLocation?) {
           if(!isDriverFound){
               isDriverFound  = true
               driverID = key!!
               // Get Driver Info
               driverInfoReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Utils.REAL_TIME_URL).reference.child("Users")
                   .child("Drivers").child(driverID)

               val driverMap = hashMapOf<String,Any>()
               driverMap["CustomerRideId"] = firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid
               driverInfoReference.updateChildren(driverMap)

               binding.callCar.text = "Getting Driver Location"
               getCurrentlyWorkingDrivers()
           }
        }

        override fun onKeyExited(key: String?) {  }

        override fun onKeyMoved(key: String?, location: GeoLocation?) {  }

        override fun onGeoQueryReady() {
            // This will keep looking for new drivers
            if(!isDriverFound){
                radius += 1
                getNearByDrivers()
            }
        }

        override fun onGeoQueryError(error: DatabaseError?) {
            Toast.makeText(this@ClientMapsActivity,"Error " + 
             error!!.message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
               .show()
        }
    })
}
```

Error Screenshot :

[image]

Driver Location:

[image]

Customer Location :

[image]

PS : I have omitted the location numbers before "." , but they are the same

Comment: You have an infinite loop where you're always increasing the radius and trying again.  You probably only want to do that if the previous search had no results.

Comment: it was without loop at first and still show the same error  , i thought about putting a condition in case the value exceeds as well but it did not work either .

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code without the loop, and with the condition in that case. I'd also like to see the code that sets `maxRadius`.

Comment: Alright I have edited the code and removed the loop condition , without the loop condition it was working fine , but for some reason it started showing that error after a while .

Comment: It seems that you have no drivers that are anywhere near `customPickUpLocation`, and this keep increasing the `radius` until it gets larger than GeoFire's maximum radius of `8587.0`.

Comment: I have checked and the customerPickUpLocation has lat and lng , and as i mentioned , it was working fine and stopped working unexpectdly , i don't know , i can edit and provide both locations customer and driver if needed for verification . Thank you

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have added some screenshots of both locations ( Customer and Driver )

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Now unfortunately I just don't see what could be going wrong anymore. Can you put a log statement as the first line inside `onKeyEntered` to see if that ever gets called?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen onKeyEntered is no longer called yeah because it gets to the code block , it will surely work , i'm puzzled as well and i'm still debugging the code